# getGraphEdge getGraphNode - What's the difference and when to use it?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm confused by those both.
In my case, I try to get data from a FB page and got this code:

```
    try {
    $response = $fb->get('/' . $sPageID . '?fields=posts', $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    $responseFeed = $fb->get('/' . $sPageID . '/feed', $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
} catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "catch";
    dd($e->getMessage());
}

$graphEdge = $responseFeed->getGraphEdge();
$tester = $response->getGraphNode();

echo "<pre>";
print_r ( $tester );
echo "</pre>";
```

`$response` and `$responseFeed` contain data. But only `$tester` contains data later on. `$graphEdge` is empty.
`$tester` offers a method: `getParentGraphEdge()` but the return value is empty as well. That happens on different URLs like `/pageID` or `/pageID?field=posts` or `/pageID/feed`

When to use getGraphEdge? And why doesn't it work here?

Answer (score 0):

How you use thoses functions is the right way. Use `getGraphNode()` when you request a node, and `getGraphEdge()` for an edge.

I don't know why the edge is empty, but try to execute your request (`/{page-id}/feed`) on the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/) with the access token in `$_SESSION['facebook_access_token']`, maybe its result is just empty.